# different post-thumbnail in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, post, thumbnails

The scenario:

I'm on the Startpage of my Blog, and there is an Article with its post-thumbnail. When I click on the Header or the "…read more-link I get to the post.

My question:

*Is it possible to set the image bigger when you're on the single-post-page? Furthermore I would like to understand how to set this post-thumbnail-difference up.*

I hope you've understood my bad english :) I'm looking forward in receiving help from you guys.

Best regards
Morten

Update:

Here two Screenshots of the Scenario:
Startpage > http://s1.directupload.net/images/130517/ltxuxyj6.png
Singlepost > http://s1.directupload.net/images/130517/lap5re2j.png

The images belongs to me (© Morten Sassi)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the theme you're using : on mine, thumbnail isn't used for the startpage but it use the "featured image", and once on the page of the article I just add the image directly in the body of the article with the size I want.

Maybe you can have a look to your template code and either edit it (but if you're using a theme you didn't create and you update it later your modifications will be deleted) or create a child theme (better solution) to edit only the files you want.

Hope this will help ^^

Comment: i updated my question by uploading two images, i hope you'll understand better :)

Comment: I understood your scenario, and I still see only two solutions : adding your image directly in the body of your post, or editing your Wordpress theme so that it will pick the right size of the picture on the startpage and on the post page (you can use the plugin "Simple Image Sizes" to add new image sizes). I'm not an expert so I won't be able to help you more than that ^^' Hope for you someone else will be able to help you ^^

Answer (score 0):

The best & easy tricky way is uplod your image from media, copy the path and paste this on your post or page editor from backend..and you will get what you want.

Thanks
anand